# Proof that the extension is galois

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm trying to find a proof for the following  statement:

Let $K_\mathfrak{p}$ be a complete field such that $\bar{K_\mathfrak{p}}$ is algebraically closed , let $f(x) \in K_\mathfrak{p}[X]$  be a polynomial.
Now let's assume that the reduction of $f$ to $\bar{K_\mathfrak{p}}$ has the form $(X-\bar\alpha)^e$.
So the field extension $L = K_\mathfrak{p}/f\cong K_\mathfrak{p}[X]/(f(x))$ is galois

Comment: The extension cut out by $x^3 - 3$ over $\mathbf{Q}_3$ is not Galois.

Comment: edited the question..

Comment: Version 2 of the question: the extension cut out by the exact same polynomial $x^3 -3$ over the maximal unramified extension of $\mathbf{Q}_3$ is not Galois.